# Ubuntu 18.04 boot into black screen with no response to any input

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, nouveau

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop (i5-8400 GTX1060). However, when I start the system, the only outcome is black screen after a short period of purple and no input can have any response, including <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>*.

It seems like some issues with the graphics driver because after pressing <kbd>e</kbd> at boot interface and replacing

```
quiet splash
```

with

```
i915.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0 nomodeset
```

the system can boot fine. But no matter how I blacklist the nouveau driver or install the nvidia driver, the system still boot into the responseless blackscreen without the procedure described above.

What on earth is wrong and how can I solve it? Please help.